# How to give Alias name for My Website

Tags: asp.net

I have deployed my ASP.Net Site in one of our server which is in ip format. So, I used to browse it like… `http://xx.xx.xx.xx/MySite`

But, I want to get out of this IP and give some text. How can I achieve this.

Also, I can’t change the Host alias name.

Answer (score 1):

you can add name for ip address in file [windows directory]/system32/drivers/etc/hosts but it works only on local machine. If you want solution for network, you should have access to DNS server

Answer (score 0):

Your server definitely has a name. You can use this name to access your site instead of ip address. smth like http://myserver/MySite

Thanks,
Arty